# find files with non existent users

Tags: command-line, ssh, filesystem

I did a time shift backup restor, but now in various place I find users or groups that don't exist. they look like User #1034 group #1010 or user #501, and I am supossing this is why many things are not working Like TCP port 80 so my server is no longer accessable
How do I find and fix these errors? fsck. I did a find find -user 1034|more, but this takes too much browsing. Perhaps a better expresion like I have used for permissions

```
find . -user old-user -exec chown new-user:new-group {} \; or sudo find . -type f ! -user 501 -exec chown 0 {} \;
```

, but how do I get an output to confirm?

What I would really like is a page on how to sting these expresions in one place as help does not give all operators and I have to brows all over to find the different parts at leat for file maniputations and grep things

Comment: You should be able to use the `-nouser` and `-nogroup` tests to find files for which no user/group corresponds to file's numeric group ID (rather than having to iterate over a list of numeric IDs explicitly)

Answer (score 1):

### If I understand correctly, the following can work for you

Create command lines with more than one `-exec` part according to the following example, the first part to show `target-file:`, and the following part(s) to perform the action(s).

```
$ sudo find /home/sudodus/Backup/ -user sudodus -exec printf "%s:\n" {} \; -exec echo do-this {} \; -exec echo do-that {} \;
[sudo] password for nio: 
/home/sudodus/Backup/:
do-this /home/sudodus/Backup/
do-that /home/sudodus/Backup/
/home/sudodus/Backup/5:
do-this /home/sudodus/Backup/5
do-that /home/sudodus/Backup/5
/home/sudodus/Backup/7:
do-this /home/sudodus/Backup/7
do-that /home/sudodus/Backup/7
/home/sudodus/Backup/6:
do-this /home/sudodus/Backup/6
do-that /home/sudodus/Backup/6
/home/sudodus/Backup/4:
do-this /home/sudodus/Backup/4
do-that /home/sudodus/Backup/4
```

where you can replace `/home/sudodus/Backup/` with the relevant directory, that you want to search; `-user` with `-nouser`, `-group`, `-nogroup`; `sudodus` with the relevant user or group; `echo do-this` and `echo do-that`  with the relevant commands. This way you can create command lines, that will do what you want and show which files that will be affected.

`-nouser`, `-nogroup` have no parameter, the command can look like this

```
sudo find /home -nouser -exec printf "%s:\n" {} \; -exec echo do-this {} \; -exec echo do-that {} \;
```

It is a good idea to start with `echo` as a 'dry run' to show that the correct things are likely to happen, and after that remove the `echo` parts of the commands to perform the action(s).